# How can I add a label to a UITableViewCell on touch?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a `UITableView` and I'm displaying `UITableViewCells`.

When I click on a cell, I want to add a label to that cell, on a new row within the cell.

I'm updating my data structure correctly, I just don't know how to add the label to the subview.

This is where I add the row to my data structure:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemdata[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].rows.append(row(size: 0))
    // need to call below method somehow to update views
}
```

This is where I think I need to add the label to the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemcell") as! itemcell
    cell.lblItemName?.text = itemdata[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].name
    if(itemdata[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].rows.count > 0){
        // dynamically add new rows to the cell in a loop
        // each row is a label on a new line
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is what the cell looks like before click:

[image: UITableViewCell]

After touching, it should look like this:

[image: UITableViewCell with 1 row]

After touching again, it should look something like this:

[image: UITableViewCell with 2 rows]

Dynamically adding new rows is what I don't know how to do.

If possible, I'd like to be able to visually design a row (with a label, buttons, etc) in a similar way that cells can be prototyped, and then add such a row to the cell. Perhaps by having an empty array of such rows within the cell which can then by increased on touch.

I don't want to do it by putting another `UITableView` inside the cell with more `UITableViewCells` inside that because I don't need the view to be scrollable and I don't want the lines between cells.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about where the problem lies? Do you know how to add subviews in code at all? Or is the problem specific to table view cells? (You're going to have a problem with the cell's height if you go this route; perhaps that's the difficulty.) Could you show some code you've actually written for the "dynamically add new rows to the cell" section?

Comment: I added the information at the bottom. That's the part I don't know how to do so I haven't written any code for it and don't know where to start.

Comment: I agree with @matt you'll have a lot of issues with cell height if you dynamically keep adding views to the cell. Perhaps a nice way to go would be to insert a new cell on tap right below the one that was tapped and style it as you please in your cellForRow method. You can use sections and numberOfRows in section for this.

Comment: I think adding new cells won't work because I don't want the cell border between those rows. It needs to be a subview of the cell or done without borders to make sense for my UI. The item cells need borders, though. Should my item cell contain another TableView with cell separators disabled where I dynamically add row cells to that?

Comment: use stackView and create dynamic uilabel and add to it into the uilabel...